# How to use external variable inside .ajax success callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
    var pType = "foo"

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/active_list?sort=id&order=asc&limit=1000&offset=0",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        },
        success: function (data) {
           console.log(pType);
        },
        statusCode: {
          ....
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           .....
        },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
```

My problem that  `console.log(pType);` doesn't return `foo`

How to achieve it ?

Comment: What does `console.log(pType);` return? Do you change `pType` anywhere?

Comment: And are you sure you hare in the success case ? do you try to `console.log` another thing, like `console.log("foo")` ?

Comment: This should work as it is (JavaScript has lexical scope, every function is a closure). If it doesn't then either your variable is defined where you think/show it is or `success` is not called at all.

Comment: The code you provided works: https://jsfiddle.net/09LL1w9g/1/ (I've changed the url to something I can access, and I'm alerting instead of console.logging). You'll need to provide some additional background.

Comment: I am guessing the problem is with the actual code and not what you pasted in here.